# display timestamp value in java from database

Tags: java, jdbc, timestamp

the value of date in database is
2011-03-19 18:49:04

```
Timestamp date;
ResultSet rs=smt.executeQuery("select * from posttopic where name='"+logn+"'");
while(rs.next()){
    name=rs.getString(1);
    title=rs.getString(2);
    subject=rs.getString(3);
    message=rs.getString(4);
    date=rs.getTimestamp(5);
    System.out.print(date);
}
```

the value of date the the above function is returning is 2011-03-19 18:49:04.0.

Why it is appending .0 at the end?How to remove it?

Comment: Unrelated to the question/problem, consider using `PreparedStatement` to save your application/DB from SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is about formatting the `Date`/`Timestamp`, not the internal precision (Date holds milliseconds). Try formatting the `Timestamp` to not show the fractional seconds, use `SimpleDateFormat` for example:
    Timestamp date;

```
ResultSet rs=smt.executeQuery("select * from posttopic where name='"+logn+"'");
// Create a date formatter with pattern as required: year-month-day hour:minute:second
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
while(rs.next())
{
    name=rs.getString(1);
    title=rs.getString(2);
    subject=rs.getString(3);
    message=rs.getString(4);
    date=rs.getTimestamp(5);
    System.out.print(sdf.format(date)); // Format the date using the specified pattern.
}
```

Comment: can you give an example in context of my question

Answer (score 6):

`java.sql.Timestamp` (as returned by `getTimestamp`) includes a nanosecond component, and its `toString()` method appends that nanosecond value to the end of the String. In your case, the nanosecond value is zero (your data only has one-second precision).

Note that while `java.sql.Timestamp` is a subclass of `java.util.Date`, you should be careful about treating it as such.  From the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html):

> This type is a composite of a `java.util.Date` and a separate nanoseconds value. Only integral seconds are stored in the `java.util.Date` component. The fractional seconds - the nanos - are separate. The `Timestamp.equals(Object)` method never returns true when passed an object that isn't an instance of `java.sql.Timestamp`, because the nanos component of a date is unknown. As a result, the `Timestamp.equals(Object)` method is not symmetric with respect to the `java.util.Date.equals(Object)` method. Also, the hashcode method uses the underlying `java.util.Date` implementation and therefore does not include nanos in its computation.
>
> Due to the differences between the `Timestamp` class and the `java.util.Date` class mentioned above, it is recommended that code not view `Timestamp` values generically as an instance of `java.util.Date`. The inheritance relationship between `Timestamp` and `java.util.Date` really denotes implementation inheritance, and not type inheritance.

Comment: To expand just a bit, you can use Java's http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html to format the Timestamp any way you want.