# update date/time in oracle database from java

Tags: java, database, systemtime

I have 2 columns in my table with data type TIMESTAMP and DATE. The column with data type "DATE" is default date/time, so that we don't need to insert from JAVA, It automatically gets inserted. For the other column with data type "TIMESTAMP" I manually insert the current time from JAVA which is optional. The actual problem is the database time differs from the time which I insert from java. ie.The default time inserted is not same as the date/time which I manually inserted from DB. Is there any way to match the database time to system time which is inserted from java?  The SQL date differs by 7-8 minutes from my system date, which should get matched while inserting it manually.

Comment: SO you are saying you want TIMESTAMP and DATE columns have same values at the end of insertions. That is current date and time?

Comment: No. The date which I inserted manually from java and the date which was inserted by default from SQL aren't same.

Comment: Please provide your current dates the you are getting/setting and  the dates that you want, in the question itself.

Comment: If the db data/time is 1:00 PM and my system date/time is 1:07 PM.

Comment: is your db on local system? Is your system's and db's timezone are same?

Comment: No they aren't same. If they are same I'll not get this problem

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert current_date in both mentioned columns and you are unable to do so:

Check if your system's (where java code is running) timezone and database's timezone are same.

In database run this query:

`SELECT dbtimezone FROM DUAL;`

and if you find it different from your java/system then you can always change it using :

```
ALTER DATABASE SET TIME_ZONE='+05:30';
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG263

EDIT 1: 
If you don't want to change the timezone you can do two things:

1) select the date/time form database in java instead of taking it from Calendar object. Then insert the same date/time to TIMESTAMP column. 
[display timestamp value in java from database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5369455/5204909)

2) set database DATE field from java instead of database itself. So apparently setting both the fields from java.
http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-timestamp-example-current-time-now

Comment: I should not change the system or db time as i could deploy the same project in some other environment. But database date should gets matched with the environment date. Is that possible?

Comment: yeah this is one solution. But considering the performance don't we have any other options?